Am I misinterpreting data from a UV sensor?
I have a UV sensor that gives me both the power in watts per square meter and the UV radiation index.
The manufacturer gives me an example of a reading and its interpretation as shown in the following image:

Now, supposedly, the radiation rate is per 25 mW per square meter.
According to the example above, those 1.5 W/m^2 must be multiplied by 40 which would give a value of 60, which is very large compared to the other value of 0.1 (index).
Where am I wrong?
Any comments or suggestions are welcome.
Update2:
I provided a link to a manual for another model, I can't find a link to the correct manual, so I leave images of the correct manual.


Why would you multiply it with 40, what does 40 mean to you? The example is also non-sensical because 1.5 watts per square meter does not equal UV index of 0.1 In that example the radiation rate is not 25 mW per square meter.

1/25mW = 40 ((A simple math rule of three)

Ah true. But you see, 250mW/squaremeter is UV index 10. Therefore if sensor reports 1.5W, it is UV index 60. I don't see the problem except the returned value is not realistic on planet earth.

That screenshot of "Slave Response" - where is it from? It is not from the datasheet you linked.

This question is similar to: Relationship between power per square meter of UV radiation and UV index. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@MrGerber Yes, it is related, but that question only refers to how to relate power to the UV index. And it seems that it has been answered correctly, unless someone else contributes something.
Instead, this question refers to the possible discordance of the values ​​obtained from the sensor.

@MrGerber
There are two pages, you can read it in the section called:
Communication Protocol（MODBUS）
Where from a host (RS485) a data frame is sent to the sensor and it responds (the OP image)

@MrGerber
I just realized that the link provided was for another similar sensor model, so I better updated the question with a picture of that part related to communication

I managed to contact the sensor's technical support and they told them that the UV index is obtained simply by dividing the power value by ten.
In this case, 1.5W/10 = 0.15, which is approximately equal to 0.1.
It seems strange to me, but they claim that it is so.
Update:
He added this to my questions:
The intensity of solar ultraviolet rays of different wavelengths up to 400nm is measured, and the intensity of solar ultraviolet rays of different wavelengths is multiplied by the corresponding weighted value in the "erythema action spectrum curve" to reflect the reaction of human skin to ultraviolet rays. The results of the above multiplications are added together to obtain the total ultraviolet intensity weighted by the erythema spectrum, in milliwatts per square meter (mW/㎡). Then the total ultraviolet intensity weighted by the erythema spectrum is multiplied by 0.04 to obtain the ultraviolet index (each unit of ultraviolet index is 0.025W/㎡)
However, our radiation value is not the total UV intensity weighted by the erythema spectrum, so it is not applicable to the formula that you mentioned .
